# Object not set to instance when calling RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

IIS Throws:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

when it is supposed to redirect a authenticated user to /Home/Index

I have investigated the reason it might be happening and can´t find the reason

The line is that:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

stacktrace: (That is the only information I get)

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) +160
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +445
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +129
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +287
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__17(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +129
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +338
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +129
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +282
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +71
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +129
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +236
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +301
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

**Edit 1:**
The application is working locally in my computer. I am coping all the folder and sending to the server. Then, I try to access locally in the server and I get this. IIS on the server has the same configuration for Application Pool and I believe it is configured right, at least for a local use as I am doing. I am trying to get it to work locally in the server and then I´ll configure for remote use.

**Edit 2:**

This is /Home/Index:

```
namespace gedaiapp.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {   
            return PartialView();
        }
    }
}
```

and the /Index/Login (Class has authorize attribute, only this specific method has `[AllowAnonymous]`) so users not yet authenticated are allowed to login

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, FormCollection form)
{
    try
    {
        //Verifica se logon será feito utilizando certificado digital ou não
        string isDigitalCertified = form["hasDigital"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(isDigitalCertified))
        {
            string[] isDCArr = isDigitalCertified.Split(',');

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(isDCArr[0]))
            {
                string isDC = isDCArr[0];

                //Se login for utilizando certificado digital
                if (isDC == "true")
                {
                    //Resgata subject do certificado digital
                    string certDadosStr = "";
                    do
                    {
                        certDadosStr = Request.ClientCertificate.Subject;
                    } while (certDadosStr == "");

                    //Resgata cpf ou cnpj do certificado digital
                    string[] certDadosArr = certDadosStr.Split(',');
                    int Count = certDadosArr.Count();
                    //Razão social é sempre o último elemento no padrão ICP-Brasil
                    string razaoSocial = certDadosArr[Count - 1];
                    string[] razaoSocialArr = razaoSocial.Split(':');
                    Count = razaoSocialArr.Count();
                    string key = razaoSocialArr[Count - 1];
                    //Resgata Guid do usuário
                    MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName);
                    Guid userID = (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey;

                    //Verifica se (cpf ou cnpj) do usuário efetuando o login é o mesmo do cadastrado no sistema
                    using (gedaiappEntities context = new gedaiappEntities())
                    {
                        var keyNumberObj = from a in context.sistema_UsersCertified
                                           where a.userID == userID
                                           select a.keyNumber;
                        string keyNumber = keyNumberObj.First();

                        //Se autenticidade for positiva (redireciona)
                        if (keyNumber == key)
                        {
                            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
                            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
                        }
                    }
                }//Caso login seja sem certificado digital
                else
                {
                    MembershipProvider mp = Membership.Provider;
                    if (mp.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
                    {
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
                        try
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            return Content("Erro: " + e);
                        }

                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //return Content("Erro Catastrófico: Não foi possivel identificar se login é com certificado digital ou não.");
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //return Content("Erro Catastrófico: Valor do checkbox hasDigital não foi enviado.");
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Content("Erro: " + e);
    }
}
```

Any help?

Comment: This stack suggests that the error is occurring during authorization filter handling (versus on the RedirectToAction line).  What does the rest of the method look like?  Do you have auth filters on the method and perhaps something is wrong with them?

Comment: @Peter I have edited my post. Check Edit 2. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: What are the hosting differences between your local dev environment and the server? Are you hosting in dev on IIS or the dev web server (Casini)? If IIS, what versions (dev and server)?  The problem isn't obvious yet.

Comment: @Peter dev is a IIS7 web server, the server is IIS6. Is that a problem?

Comment: It's possible. There are differences between IIS 6 and 7 when it comes to dealing with MVC apps. Although, the error you are presenting doesn't seem like it should be related to IIS versions.  However, I can't come up with a reason for it.  Are you certain of the line that's throwing the exception?  The line you presented seems like a very unlikely candidate. I'd suspect something else in that method.  Perhaps you could try an empty method (just return `Content("test")`) with the same attributes to test for attribute behavior.

Comment: @GuilhermeLongo, when you deployed to production, did you create a deployable dependancies folder in your solution explorer?

Comment: @Peter I can return a string right before this line. I know, its very wierd. I have tried removing the [authorize] attribute but it does make any difference. I´ll try to remove the site on IIS and recreate again. Does not seens to be a problem with the app.

Comment: @DaveA, I have not created anything. Just for test purpose I have copied the whole project folder so It shoud be working.

Comment: @Peter Reding this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693905/object-not-set-to-instance-when-calling-redirecttoaction#comment20548800_14693905 I have added this line: <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> and It worked. I know I should not be doing that, so as I have no experience does it make any sense? So what is wrong? What is not loading that when I use this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem adding

`<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>`

in the web.config

P.S. It is not the right way to do as it will load all modules at every request. Although can´t find what is not loading.

Comment: That's because you're using IIS6 in production. You need that tag so that all the requests get routed through the `aspnet_isapi` filter. It's an issue with IIS6 and MVC I'm afraid.

Comment: @levelnis Thanks... I am felling better now that this is not a development issue. Thanks.